# Computing statistics on a pandas dataframe groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
Name   Date   Measurement  Lower     Upper 
blue   N/A     1.2         .2           1
blue   N/A     1.4         .2           1
red    N/A     2.2         .2           1
orange N/A     1.6         .2           1
purple N/A     3.2         .2           1
.
.
.
```

using
`df = df_old.groupby(['color']).agg({'Measurement':['mean',std']})`
I got the new dataframe;

```
       Measurement
Name    mean   std
blue    2.4    .021
orange  1.5    .011
purple  2.2    .023
red     2.1    .054
```

I also want to compute the CpK and add it as a column to the dataframe as shown bellow:

```
       Measurement
Name    mean   std    cpk
blue    2.4    .021    1.2
orange  1.5    .011    .21
purple  2.2    .023    .23
red     2.1    .054    .24
```

I was not able to find a way using the agg() function something like.agg('cpk')...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47146421/

Comment: What's `CpK`? how do you compute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to create a custom function that returns a Series of the mean, std and a specific function like cpk using apply:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    d={}
    mu=x['Measurement'].mean()
    std=x['Measurement'].std()
    USL=x.Upper.values[0]
    LSL=x.Lower.values[0]
    cpk=np.min([(USL-mu)/(3*std),(mu-LSL)/(3*std)])
    d['Measurement_mean']=mu
    d['Measurement_std']=std
    d['Measurement_cpk']=cpk
    return pd.Series(d, index=['Measurement_mean', 'Measurement_std',
                                      'Measurement_cpk'])

df=df_old.groupby(['Name']).apply(f)
```

I used the standard formula for the cpk calculation of normally distributed data, which is only valid for processes that are in a state of statistical control.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I wanted.  Thanks much.  Learned about .apply().  Thanks.